# Splitting on whitespace character and strip empty fields

Tags: perl, split, whitespace

```
($red, $tapinfo) = split(/:/, $line);
@fields = split(/\s+/, $tapinfo);
```

In the array fields, I see that even space gets added. I want to eliminate the space so that fields only contains non-space characters. Please comment on what can be going wrong.

Comment: Show your input please.

Comment: This works nice for me.

Comment: Do you have leading whitespace? Split on `' '` will remove it then split on `\s+`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are talking about leading whitespace remaining, so that `@fields` looks something like:

```
$VAR1 = [
          '',    # empty field
          'foo',
          'bar'
        ];
```

This is because you are using `/\s+/` for your `split` when you should be using the default `' '` (a single blank space character). This default behaviour will strip leading whitespace before splitting the string. In other words, you should do:

```
@fields = split(' ', $tapinfo);
```

This is documented in [perldoc -f split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html):

```
As another special case, "split" emulates the default behavior
of the command line tool awk when the PATTERN is either omitted
or a *literal string* composed of a single space character (such
as ' ' or "\x20", but not e.g. "/ /"). In this case, any leading
whitespace in EXPR is removed before splitting occurs, and the
PATTERN is instead treated as if it were "/\s+/"; in particular,
this means that *any* contiguous whitespace (not just a single
space character) is used as a separator. However, this special
treatment can be avoided by specifying the pattern "/ /" instead
of the string " ", thereby allowing only a single space
character to be a separator.
```

Answer (score 0):

What `split` does *by default* is the same as

```
my @list = $string =~ /\S+/g;
```

i.e. it finds all the contiguous substrings of non-whitespace characters.

You could use the regex, but to to get the default behaviour from `split`, pass a single literal space character as the first parameter. ***Not*** a regex. The documentation says this

> As another special case, split emulates the default behavior of the command line tool awk when the PATTERN is either omitted or a literal string composed of a single space character (such as ' ' or "\x20" , but not e.g. / / ). In this case, any leading whitespace in EXPR is removed before splitting occurs, and the PATTERN is instead treated as if it were /\s+/ ; in particular, this means that any contiguous whitespace (not just a single space character) is used as a separator.